# is it a vector space or not?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, definition

check if  this is a vector space or not ?

1- let $v=R=\{(x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ check if

$(V,+,.)$ where 
       $(x,y)+(z,w)=(x,y)$
     and  $k.(x,y)=(k.x,k.y)$ is a vector space or not

2- let $v=R=\{(x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$check if
   $(v,+,.)$ where 
    $(x,y)+(z,w)=(x+z,y+w)$
      $k(x,y) = (kx,ky)$

Comment: In 1, addition is not abelian, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) it is not a vector space because $(V,+)$ is not a group (no identity element).

(2) It is a vector space, try to verify it with your definition of vector space (it is easy tell me if you encounter a difficulty).

Comment: i have difficulty to do that  i need full definition  please

Comment: the definition is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition, try to verify all the anxioms...